# Is it possible to clone with hgsubversion in steps?

Tags: mercurial, clone, hgsubversion

I'm trying to clone a rather large subversion repository with **hgsubversion**.

```
hg clone --startrev 8890 svn+https://my.reposit.ory/trunk trunk_hg
```

After about an hour, the `clone` operation aborts with an *out of memory* message:

```
[r20097] user: description
abort: out of memory
```

Is it possible to specify an end revision for the `clone` operation and get the remaining revisions with a `pull`? Or somehow break up the `clone` in smaller steps?

Comment: Found just now the [doc](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/src/tip/hgsubversion/help/subversion.rst), where the *out of memory* condition is mentioned and also the solution of the accepted answer; currently (r777) on lines 228..238 of the referenced document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a stop revision with -r for clone, as others have suggested. Another option (if you kept the clone where things crashed) would be to just run `hg pull` in the `trunk_hg` copy. You might have to edit/create `.hg/hgrc` yourself to add the `[paths]\n default = svn+https://my.reposit.ory/trunk`, since I think we add that at the end of the cloning process. Maybe run `hg svn rebuildmeta` before your pull just for good measure in case the tracking metadata for hgsubversion got hosed when the OOM happened.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Stupid me! Didn't realise that `-r` specifies a stop revision, not a range of changesets. Now it works. `hg clone --startrev 8890 -r 10000 ...` initialised the repo and subsequent `hg pull -r xxxx` let me add the remaining subversion revisions.

Comment: Unfortunately a `pull` after the OOM doesn't work, as the repo retrieved so far gets automatically deleted after the abort.

Comment: At the end of every `pull` an abort message appears: `pulled xxx revisions \n abort: 00changelog.i@11000: no node!`. Any explications for this? It seems not to be a problem, as I can continue to pull.

Comment: No, I've never observed that error here. If it's harmless, I guess I'd just suggest ignoring it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `hg pull -r 4951` → `** Unknown exception encountered with possibly-broken third-party extension hgsubversion` ... `ValueError: 20-byte hash required`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone

Could try using the `-r <revid>` flag to clone only a particular changeset. Though that may or may not work with hgsvn.

Comment: When i specify `-r 8890:20000`, I get the error `unrecognised Subversion revision 8890:20000: only numbers work.`

Answer (score 1):

Cloning with a limited range of revisions and then pulling is the recommended method and I can confirm that it works flawlessly for svn repositories in the several GB size range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to clone the whole svn repo:

1. start cloning
2. abort it immediately (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in windows)
3. than hg pull
4. you've got out of memory
5. repeat step 3 until you check out all commits